# How to apply date format and number format in vba

Tags: excel, vba, fixed-width

How to change the format of a column to date format and number format with including currency sign & thousand separators.

I am new to vba and found a function from cpearson.  Trying to run the function, but not able to apply the format.

Below is the code

```
Function ImportFixedWidth(FileName As String, _
     StartCell As Range, _
     IgnoreBlankLines As Boolean, _
     SkipLinesBeginningWith As String, _
     ByVal FieldSpecs As String) As Long

  Dim FINdx As Long
  Dim C As Long
  Dim R As Range
  Dim FNum As Integer
  Dim S As String
  Dim RecCount As Long
  Dim FieldInfos() As String
  Dim FInfo() As String
  Dim N As Long
  Dim T As String
  Dim B As Boolean

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
    On Error GoTo EndOfFunction:

    If Dir(FileName, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
        ' file not found
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Len(FieldSpecs) < 3 Then
        ' invalid FieldSpecs
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    If StartCell Is Nothing Then
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set R = StartCell(1, 1)
    C = R.Column
    FNum = FreeFile

    Open FileName For Input Access Read As #FNum
    ' get rid of any spaces
    FieldSpecs = Replace(FieldSpecs, Space(1), vbNullString)
    ' omit double pipes ||
    N = InStr(1, FieldSpecs, "||", vbBinaryCompare)
    Do Until N = 0
        FieldSpecs = Replace(FieldSpecs, "||", "|")
        N = InStr(1, FieldSpecs, "||", vbBinaryCompare)
    Loop
    ' omit double commas
    N = InStr(1, FieldSpecs, ",,", vbBinaryCompare)
    Do Until N = 0
        FieldSpecs = Replace(FieldSpecs, ",,", ",")
        N = InStr(1, FieldSpecs, ",,", vbBinaryCompare)
    Loop

    ' get rid of leading and trailing | characters, if necessary
    If StrComp(Left(FieldSpecs, 1), "|", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        FieldSpecs = Mid(FieldSpecs, 2)
    End If
    If StrComp(Right(FieldSpecs, 1), "|", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        FieldSpecs = Left(FieldSpecs, Len(FieldSpecs) - 1)
    End If

    Do
        ' read the file
        Line Input #FNum, S
        If SkipLinesBeginningWith <> vbNullString And _
                StrComp(Left(Trim(S), Len(SkipLinesBeginningWith)), _
                SkipLinesBeginningWith, vbTextCompare) Then
            If Len(S) = 0 Then
                If IgnoreBlankLines = False Then
                    Set R = R(2, 1)
                Else
                    ' do nothing
                End If
            Else
                ' allow code to change the FieldSpecs values

                If FieldSpecs = vbNullString Then
                    ' FieldSpecs is empty. Do nothing, don't import.
                Else
                    If ImportThisLine(S) = True Then
                        FieldInfos = Split(FieldSpecs, "|")
                        C = R.Column
                       For FINdx = LBound(FieldInfos) To UBound(FieldInfos)
                           FInfo = Split(FieldInfos(FINdx), ",")
                            R.EntireRow.Cells(1, C).Value = Mid(S, CLng(FInfo(0)), CLng(FInfo(1)))
                            C = C + 1
                        Next FINdx
                        RecCount = RecCount + 1
                    End If
                    Set R = R(2, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' no skip first char
        End If

    Loop Until EOF(FNum)

    EndOfFunction:
```

Comment: Changing format of a range (in your case, column) is done using `Range.Numberformat` - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) for documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the sheet is "Sheet1", you can use:

```
Sub macro1()
With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@" 
'or "yy/mm/dd;@" , depending on your country settings
.Columns("D").NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"
End With
End Sub
```